# React Hooks: How can I turn my AuthUserRole (Role Based Auth) Component (HOC) into a React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, higher-order-components

**My Goal:**

I have a component `AuthUserRole.tsx` that accepts a component and and a userRole (Admin, Manager, Employee). If the `userRole` is allowed, it returns the wrapped component. If the `userRole` is NOT allowed, the HOC redirects the user to the Home Screen. **This all works.**

**My Question:**

Is it possible/more efficient/more modern of a practice to **convert this HOC into a Custom React Hook?** Below is how the current `AuthUserRole` HOC works + the `AuthUserRole` component.

**How AuthUserRole.tsx Is Used:**

```js
// Imports: Components
import Account from './pages/account/Account';

// Restricted Routes
const RestrictedAccount = AuthUserRole(Account, ['Admin', 'Manager', 'Employee']);

// React App
const App: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Route path="/account" component={RestrictedAccount} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**AuthUserRole.tsx:**

```js
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Redirect, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

// Imports: TypeScript Types
import { ReduxState, UserRole } from '../../types/types';

// Component: Auth (User Role)
const AuthUserRole = (WrappedComponent: React.FC<RouteProps>, allowedRoles: Array<UserRole>) => {
  // With Auth User Role
  return class WithAuthUserRole extends React.Component {
    // FIX LATER: HARDCODED FOR NOW
    state = {
      user: {
        role: 'Admin',
        // role: 'Manager',
        // role: 'Employee',
      },
    };

    render() {
      // User Role
      const { role } = this.state.user;

      // Allowed Route
      if (allowedRoles.includes(role as UserRole)) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }
      // Forbidden Route
      else {
        return (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/',
              state: {
                // from: props.location,
                error: 'Forbidden: Not Authorized',
              }
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }
  };
};

// Exports
export default AuthUserRole;
```

Comment: Could you show a pseudo-example of how you would want the hook to work for a user of the hook?

Comment: Currently, the HOC is used such as `const RestrictedAccount = AuthUserRole(Account, ['Admin', 'Manager', 'Employee']);` I would like the hook to look pretty much the same `const RestrictedAccount = useAuthUserRole(Account, ['Admin', 'Manager', 'Employee']);`

Comment: The result, `RestrictedAccount` suggests that your hook returns a component, which is bit weird/unusual for hooks. Why not just keep your HoC because that example suggests that you are looking for the exact same pattern that HoC offers.

Comment: Yea, I was just exploring the idea and seeing if there was a more modern practice or some clarification than a HOC is the right fit for the task.